# Desperate Housewives in Brazil

Tags: visual, sports

*I've been a bit excited about the Olympic Games lately, so decided to make a simple teaser about them. Please excuse my poor drawing, that's the best I could do on my laptop.*

Five desperate housewives - Tina, Sarah, Barbara, Francesca, and Victoria, were on a vacation in Brazil for the summer, so decided they could as well visit the Olympic Games in Rio. They bought tickets for several events, dressed up in their finest clothes, and went to the Olympic facility. However, once they got there, one of them wasn't allowed to enter. Which one?

[image]

Comment: This puzzle *looks* very promising, but I'll resever my +1 vote for when I see the answer. I hope there is a clear, singular, well justified answer?

Comment: Why do I have to think of Google's homepage when I see this picture? I *do* want to see something in between your drawings, I guess... Just, *I don't* (so far).

Comment: @BmyGuest, I believe the answer becomes clear once you learn/notice it. My mediocre drawing skills may be an issue with figuring out the puzzle however, so I consider answering it myself. I expected it to be easy and fun, but it may end up too frustrating...

Comment: I think reassuring puzzlers that this is not a "guess the odd one out" type of game-puzzle, but a *real* puzzle with an - once discovered - obviouse and singular solution - is the right way to go. I dissagree with the VTC vote so far - because of the benefit of the doubt. But if it *is* just a guessing-puzzle, I would recommend removing it. (I kind of like your drawing style. Have seen worse here...) Oh, don't self-answer for at least a week! (or end of Rio2016) :c)

Comment: I think it is a valid puzzle, albeit not the very best I've seen. But with the "visual" tag (and none other) it seems within the scope as far as I'm concerned. However, you *should not* have answerd it that quickly. (**I** would not have found it, but I think others would.)

Comment: If you wouldn't find it, then hardly anyone would, or at least it would take too long to do so. Since this wasn't my intention at all, I decided to answer the question anyway. I also voted to close it, but it seems more votes are needed for that.

P.S. Let me know if you need any drawing services in the future:)

Comment: I liked this! I don't think you should have answered it so quickly, nor should people have been so quick to VTC.

Comment: Thanks @MorganG. Bmyguest - yes, these a really good ideas, and probably I could improve the story as well.

Comment: I'm not sure about "desperate housewives"...but I did like the puzzle.

Comment: all of them, since its not summer in Brasil right now

Comment: I like the edit. The "puzzle" part becomes much clearer now. I think the upvotes on this are deserved.

Comment: @BmyGuest, I'm not sure about the puzzle quality, but would gladly accept the upvotes for the sheer amount of time I spent drawing this yesterday.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since it seems the question was mis-read, and it wasn't my intention to frustrate anyone, I provide the correct answer as intended:

> Each of the housewives is wearing a ball patch from a popular sport - tennis (Tina), soccer (Sarah), basketball (Barbara), American football (Francesca), volleyball (Victoria). Out of these 5 sports, only American football is not part of the Olympic Games, and therefore the correct answer is Francesca.

Or, more visually:

> [image]

Comment: @BmyGuest, the system says I must wait for 2 more days. If I can put the correct answer somehow on top and then accept the "gingers have no souls" answer, this would also be fine

Comment: No, rather wait those two days and then accept it. Think of it "from the future perspective". People might find the puzzle in future, want to solve it themeselves, and then check the correct answer. It *is* the best (and correct) answer, after all. Giving out reputation etc. is really not the point of this site. *Testing* puzzle-ideas and *learning* how to solve or built good puzzles is (IMHO).

Comment: But Football is in the Olympics

Comment: @Oak not american football.

Comment: @ArturKirkoryan Yes, please don't accept my answer! It was more for fun than a serious one. And this puzzle was definitely a good one.

Comment: Your football ball looks like old rugby ball and rugby is on Olympics schedule. http://www.rugbyfootballhistory.com/ball.htm

Comment: @Areeb Just because I can call Tennis to me swinging a racket at people's faces in my backyard doesn't mean it's actually tennis and should be in the olympics

Comment: @Oak it's pretty obvious that the drawing is referring to what Americans refer to as football

Comment: Let's just say gridiron football and be done with it @Oak

Answer (score 8):

The one in the middle because...

> She isn't wearing any of the Olympic colors: Blue, Yellow, Black, Green, Red.
>  (The one on the far right at least has red hair so she counts.)

---

<sub>Or, having a little fun if only there was a lateral thinking tag, the one second from the left (in black) isn't allowed because...</sub>

> <sub>Human bodies aren't shaped like that and she was called out as a tiny alien controlling a robot body.</sub>

Comment: But the one in the middle is wearing black.

Comment: Top of the dress is black on the middle (tie part) so if this is the reason I would say it is the last one.

Comment: Hmm, not wearing olympic colours doesn't seem like an *exclusion criterium* at the Olympics to me....

Comment: Thanks for your answer (especially the second one:). I had something else in mind though, so in order not to confuse others, I posted my solution below.

Answer (score 7):

The second from the left because :

> She is wearing clothes with a rope, and [ropes are forbidden](https://smsprio2016-a.akamaihd.net/documents/Rio2016_prohibited_and_restricted_items.pdf).

Or :

> The ginger one, because [ginger have no souls](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EY39fkmqKBM).

Comment: +1 from me for the ginger as well. I had something else in mind however, and posted my answer below.

Comment: Oh well :) as a European, football doesn't mean this to me ;) !

Answer (score 5):

Assuming they are in order

> Francesca (second from the right)

because

> She is dressed as an American Football, and they don't do that at the Olympics.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

> The second from the left (the black pentagon) because 
> 1) she is wearing baggy clothing that may used to conceal a prohibited item or
> 2) (if this is just an "odd one out puzzle") she is the only one wearing angular clothing.  The rest of the women are curvy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the second one was a good observations. I had something else in mind however, and decided to post my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

My answer:

> Victoria, the one in black.

Explanation:

> Concerning the naming convention: 
>  Each silhouette resembles the capital letters of each housewife's name. 
>  In the-second-woman-from-the-left's case, her silhouette clearly mimics the letter V, hence she is Victoria.
>
> Now, concerning the reason for the denied 
> entry:
>
>  Victoria is wearing a very loose, black 
> poncho-styled outfit, as well as stilettos 
> which enable her to easily conceal 
> unauthorized items. As it is very crowded 
> and busy during the olympics, and for the 
> purposes of saving time (to avoid delays), Victoria was not
>  'invited' for additional screening, but 
> was simply denied entry until she wears a 
> more 'appropriate' outfit.

Comment: The naming convention is apparently from left to right. This being a visual puzzle, and not a lateral thinking one, this seems to miss the point.